# Running load tests from home network

Tags: testing, load, bandwidth, loadrunner

I need to perform a load test using loadrunner to simulate load generated from external network (My home network) on servers placed in some organization in the same region.

The application which will be tested is a web site (Not Heavy one) which users can be logged into and get personal information.

I am very concerned that my home network bandwidth wouldn't be enough to generate the following load :

I need to simulate 250 Web concurrent users which will perform about 30,000 transactions in an hour.

My home network specs and statistics:

Download - 75M - 7.5 Megabyte/sec

Upload  - 3.5 M - 350Kbyte / sec

From your experience is this would be enough to generate the desired load? If not what can be done to simulate load from external network?

Comment: To generate load you should look more at the loadrunner machine's configuration. Would your controller and/or load generator machines be able to generate the required load?

Comment: In production is your test website going to be accessed from outside?

Comment: Yes in the production environment the  website should be accessed from the outside.

Comment: A single machine with 2 cores and 2 GB of RAM should be able to generate about 1000 virtual users in this protocol. my concern is that i will have bottlenecks on the network.

Comment: So, in terms of generating load you should look at your Lgs capabilities. The network bandwidth will not impact load generation but they may increase load time. However because the site is ultimately going to be accessed from outside so you should be ok running from your home in terms of bandwidth. To be on the safe side i would inquire if there are any expectations to the kind of bandwith normal users would have. Does that make sense?

Comment: bandwidth does impact response times so you'll have to check what are normal bandwidth expectations in the region where the website will run.

Answer (score 2):

1. One Load Generator is never enough from a process perspective.  Consider at least three, two for primary load and one for a control set.   So, right off of the bat you are likely to have issues.
2. Mentioned previously.  Go to the cloud: Amazon, CloudAzure, GoDaddy, Rackspace, 1&1, etc...  all have virtual machines that you can use for performance testing hosts running load generator software.   More locations is better as this minimizes the influence of one host network over another if you are looking for representative experiences.    Odds are your site will be on one backbone and some of your load generators may have to peer over from another backbone.  This is not bad as this provides a more realistic view of your end user experiences from different locations.
3. Check your end user agreement from your home.   Unless you have a business class agreement from your home such traffic may appear to be a DDOS event, setting off alarms at your service provider.   Don't be surprised if you find yourself suddenly cut off from the internet without warning.   I have seen this happen before with people attempting to generate load from their homes against a site.

Comment: +1 for DDOS attack..About the cloud services, there generally have a shared infra. Is that in anyway going to impact the load generation?

Comment: Yes, they will shut down your connection.   Having a single point of constriction in your test design is a sure path to failure.   Odds are this person is also generating load directly from the controller, which would also be a bad sign.   Bit the bullet, pay for the additional generators up front or you will pay for it in rerunning tests or lost credibility on the back end

Comment: On the cloud services, most of them sit on multiple backbone providers with very high speed connections.  You are unlikely to impact their infrastructure with 250 virtual users.  Although the cycle rate is quite high when you look at each user having to cycle 120 times per hour, with the assumption of one "transaction" per iteration this is one iteration every 30 seconds.   My gut says "caution Will Robinson" on the load model for number of users and cycle rate.

Comment: The 7.5MB per second also translates to 60 Megabits per second.  Only a small fraction of households are going to have speeds this fast.  The 60 megabits would also be for no delays, retransmissions or errors.   Yet another reason not to handle this from home.

Comment: Agreed. I have a 20Mbps connection and i don't always get the same speed.

Comment: Thanks, the points you made are useful and i will take them in account.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the comments, the amount of load you can generate is affected not only by the network bandwidth but also by the script itself and the LG machine specifications. What I mean is that there is no definitive answer to your question without taking all the parameters into account.

What you should do is create an account on one of the popular cloud providers (Amazon, Azure, HP) and create a machine with the exact specifications you need based on the parameters as you know them. Most of these services allow you to increase the machine size and the bandwidth if needed for some extra pay.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply i will consider this seriously.